# Did part of the Jewish community move to Greece after the destruction of the First Temple?

Tags: history, babylonian-exile

Is there any evidence in Chazal, that after the destruction of the First Temple, some part of the Jewish community moved to **Greece**? (Of course, the majority moved to Babylon.)

Comment: Why do you suspect they might have? Greece wasn't much of thing in the 6th century bce

Comment: It’s a possibility, as there are Jews in Djeba an Island near Tunisia. So there could have been Jews who moved to Greece on the way to Djerba. Just surmising.

Comment: Is this question [on-topic](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), considering it seems to be asking about history of Jews, rather than history of Judaism?

Comment: In Joel 4;6 וּבְנֵי יְהוּדָה וּבְנֵי יְרוּשָׁלִַם מְכַרְתֶּם לִבְנֵי הַיְּוָנִים לְמַעַן הַרְחִיקָם מֵעַל גְּבוּלָם But there are different opinions in what time Joel lived, so I'm looking for another proof if any exists, that they also moved to Greek.

Comment: TheGlacier, I agree with @TamirEvan that this isn't on-topic as currently written. If you're trying to validate or date this mention in Joel, then I recommend re-writing the question accordingly, which would be on-topic. I don't think that the inclusion "or Chazal" makes this question about Jewish population history on-topic; if you were asking specifically from evidence from Jewish-religion sources, that would be about Judaism, but it looks like you're looking for general historical evidence, some of which may happen to come from Judaism sources.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know yet about the existence of Jewish in Greece before 300 BCE.

> The first recorded mention of Judaism in Greece dates from 300 to 250
> BCE on the island of Rhodes. In the 2nd century BCE, Hyrcanus, a
> leader in the Jewish community of Athens, was honoured by the raising
> of a statue in the agora [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Jews_in_Greece#cite_note-SephardicStudies3-13). ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Jews_in_Greece#History_of_Judaism_in_Greece))

Anyway, in Joel 4;6 it's written:
וּבְנֵי יְהוּדָה וּבְנֵי יְרוּשָׁלִַם מְכַרְתֶּם **לִבְנֵי הַיְּוָנִים** לְמַעַן הַרְחִיקָם מֵעַל גְּבוּלָם

But there are different opinions on what time Joel lived, so we can't say surely that this is about the first generation of the first temple destruction period.